# Subscribing to Batch Mutations with AWS AppSync

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-apollo, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm building a React Native app with AWS AppSync to manage data stored in DynamoDB. I've recently added some batch mutations but cannot seem to get subscriptions to the batch mutations to fire at all.

Is it even possible to have a subscription to a batch mutation? Below is my schema. All the mutations and `onAnyMilkChange` work as expected, but `onBatchUpdateMilk` never fires.

```
type Mutation {
  createMilk(input: MilkInput!): Milk
  updateMilk(input: MilkInput!): Milk
  batchUpdateMilk(input: [MilkInput]!): [Milk]
}

type Subscription {
  onAnyMilkChange(milkStashID: String): Milk @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["updateMilk","createMilk"])
  onBatchUpdateMilk(milkStashID: String): [Milk] @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["batchUpdateMilk"])
}
```

Comment: Currently subscriptions in AppSync don't work in the batched way that you mentioned in your example. For example your mutation returns an array of Milk objects and you want the subscription to fire for every item from that array. It can only work with the subscription having fields such as milkStashId coming from objects such as Milk outside of arrays.